# Syntax problem--How to use Where clause within Excel for pulling from Worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, where-clause, adodb

I figured out how to pull, but having trouble limiting the result.
How do you pull with a where clause.

See picture that shows my sheet structure for a tab called "Data"

See code below to pull the data.

I am trying to figure out the right syntax for composing the strSQL variable below.

[image: Excel with Sheet named Data]

Here is what I get:
! Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)':  Automation error

My sql string looks like this through the watch window:
"SELECT * FROM [Data$A2:G1000] where [First]='JOHN'"

CODE:

```
Sub SQL()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String



    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    Dim temp As String
    temp = Trim("G" + Trim(Str(1000)))


    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$A2:" + Trim(temp) + "] where [First]='JOHN'"

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    MsgBox rs.GetString

    MsgBox "Data Loaded"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your WHERE clause. But what is `MaxCars`?  Did you try `debug.print strSQL` before `rs.Open` to check the SQL you're building?

Comment: When you attempt the data pull with the where-clause, do you get any errors? If so, which errors?

Comment: Here is what I get for strSQL in the watch window.  I will post the error message into the question itself...  "SELECT * FROM [Data$A2:G1000] where [First]='JOHN'"

Comment: I replaced MaxCars with 1000.

Comment: I also tried:      strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$A2:" + Trim(temp) + "] where [First] = ""JOHN"""        same error.

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove the `where [First]='JOHN'`?

Comment: I think its the connection... I am not sure yet.  Looking into it.

Comment: how would you know what connection to use.  i usually find, cut and paste.  is there a web page explaining which connection to use... I am using 32 bit version of office on 64 bit machine.   But if it was a connection issue, then it shouldn't have worked without the where condition either, right?  so maybe its not the connection.....

Comment: CLR, without where clause it pulls fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

big boo boo... I needed to start with A1 and include the titles in my range.
It wasn't a syntax error, but vBA doesn't give you very good error messages!

Comment: Ha! Yes, I see it now. Looking in row 2 for your headers. Can't believe I didn't spot that.